# How is Newton's 3rd law applied in rocket propulsion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram, rocket-science

I'm really wanting to get into physics more and I've had this question for a while. I do know a bit about rocketry as I think it's pretty cool but I'm still struggling to understand how Newton's 3rd law applies on a more microscopic level. In a rocket, propellant is used to produce often very hot gas going very fast. This gas then exits through a rocket nozzle. Newton's 3rd law says that this gas moving with a lot of force away from the rocket will cause the rocket to experience an equal and opposite force thus allowing the rocket to liftoff. I'm curious where the actual collisions happen as the rocket *seems* to just eject the exhaust without the particles "hitting" anywhere to allow the force to occur. If anything needs clarifying I'd be happy to try!

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/593784/27732 (not your exact scenario, but related)

Comment: Related from Space SE: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39938/static-forces-on-a-rocket-engine and https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45336/does-thrust-depend-on-rocket-chamber-shape?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The gas particles moving out provide thrust (moving particles carry momentum , change in momentum of the rocket causes force -2nd law of Newton), I don't  know if you have experienced this but if you hold a water hose with gush of water flowing, it pushes you back

Comment: @Andrew that makes a lot of sense thank you!

Comment: @BowlOfRed Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to think about it, depending on how you want to think about gases.  You can think of gasses as having a pressure.  When a rocket is burning, there is a very high pressure inside the rocket.  That pressure pushes gas downward, but also pushes up on the rocket.

The other approach is to think of individual molecules of gas.  They aren't just going straight down.  They bounce around with thermal energy (they're *very* hot).  Those gas molecules sometimes collide with the rocket, imparting momentum to the rocket.

Both are valid ways of thinking about a rocket motor, it just depends on how you want to treat them.  Sometimes its best to think of the gasses as a fluid.  Other times its best to think of it as a bunch of particles.  But both have a rationale for why the rocket goes upward.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*I'm curious where the actual collisions happen as the rocket seems to just eject the exhaust without the particles "hitting" anywhere to allow the force to occur.*

The "collision" at which Newton's Third Law provides propulsion is at the moment that the particles *leave the rocket*, not when they hit something else.  Think of a collection of gas particles as a large macroscopic object. The rocket is throwing that object down with some force.  But, by Newton's Third Law, the object must then be exerting a force on the rocket (as it is being thrown).  That is the upward lift force on the rocket.

About where the collision occurs microscopically, Andrew's answer linked in his comment provides a nice model.

Comment: I think I somewhat understand the concept, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just supplementing other good answers. Not attempting a complete answer myself:

---

> I'm curious where the actual collisions happen as the rocket seems to just eject the exhaust without the particles "hitting" anywhere...

Most modern rocket engines have some variation on the [*de Laval nozzle*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle) at the business end. The purpose of the nozzle is to extract energy from the expansion of the gas, and use it to propel the rocket in the desired direction.

High pressure gas, exits from the "throat" of the nozzle into the "bell" at high velocity. That gas already has done work, pushing the rocket in the desired direction. But then, the gas expands inside the bell. The pupose of the bell is to "catch" the expanding gas cloud and re-direct more of it in the opposite direction to the way we want the rocket to go.

For many of the gas molecules, the last thing they pushed on, directly or indirectly,* is the wall of the bell.

---

* "indirectly" meaning, a molecule pushed on some other molecule that pushed on some other molecule...that pushed on the bell.

Comment: Thank you a bunch! The indirect collisions also made a lot of sense!